# Why does variable pass on create, but not on destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form on the chords/:id/show page (shown below). I am able to input a :note_id into the form, which then creates a ChordNote using the :chord_id from :params and the :note_id from the form. This works well. However, when I try to delete a ChordNote using the same form, I get an error that says:

NoMethodError in ChordNotesController#destroy, undefined method '[]' for nil:nilClass

This is the controller for 'ChordNote', which joins chords and notes in a many-to-many relationship.

```
def create
    @chord = Chord.find(params[:chordnote][:chord_id])
    @note = Note.find(params[:chordnote][:note_id])

    if @chord.hasnote?(@note)
        # Add error message here, have it not redirect
        redirect_to @chord
    else
        @chord.addnote!(@note)
        redirect_to @chord
    end
end

def destroy
    @chord = Chord.find(params[:chordnote][:chord_id])
    @note = Note.find(params[:chordnote][:note_id])
        Chordnote.find_by(note_id: @note.id, chord_id: @chord.id).destroy
    redirect_to chord_path(@chord)
end
```

This is the form (that appears on chords/:id/show):

```
    <%= form_for(@chord.chordnotes.build(chord_id: @chord.id)) do |f| %>
          <div><%= f.hidden_field :chord_id, value: @chord.id %></div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_field :note_id, placeholder: "Enter the note's id" %>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit "Add Note", class: "btn btn-large" %>
          <%= link_to "Remove Note", Chordnote.find_by(note_id: 1), method: :delete, title: "test title", class: "btn btn-large" %>
    <% end %>
```

Any thoughts on why destroy is not working? Thanks!

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

```
def destroy
    ####The error is on the following line####
    @chord = Chord.find(params[:chordnote][:chord_id])

    @note = Note.find(params[:chordnote][:note_id])

    Chordnote.find_by(note_id: @note.id, chord_id: @chord.id).destroy

    redirect_to chord_path(@chord)
```

Rails.root: /Users/mydocs/myprojects/rails_projects/what_key_v002

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/chordnotes_controller.rb:23:in `destroy'
Request
```

Posted parameters:

```
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "id"=>"10"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `destroy` action, you're trying to make a lookup off `params[:chordnote][:note_id]`, but the only available parameters are `{"_method"=>"delete", "id"=>"10"}`. You need to add both `note_id` and `chord_id` as arguments in your `link_to` helper:

```
<%= link_to "Remove Note", chordnote_path(:chord_id => @chord.id, :note_id => 1), :method => :delete %>
# => <a href="/chordnote?chord_id=your_chord_id&amp;note_id=1">Remove Note</a>
```

Then, in your `destroy` action, make your lookups off `params[:chord_id]` and `params[:note_id]`:

```
def destroy
    Chordnote.find_by(note_id: params[:note_id], chord_id: params[:chord_id]).destroy
    redirect_to chord_path(params[:chord_id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I'd like to be able to input the :note_id in the form, instead of having it hard-coded as '1'. How can I adjust this as well? Thanks again

Comment: Hey, thanks to your suggestion I was actually able to get a step closer to what I really want, which is have a 'remove note' link right after each note (they are listed on the chord's show page). I think I should be able to use jQuery to 'climb the DOM' to get the note's ID (which is in the <div id="note-" + @note.id>) and pass that in the link, but I'm not sure how to integrate this jQuery function into the rails code.

Comment: Happy it helped. Since it did, would you kindly consider accepting/voting up this answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
Chordnote.find_by(note_id: @note.id, chord_id: @chord.id)
```

cant find a record, so its nil and nil doesnt have a method called destroy.
Are you sure you are passing the correct params to the action?

Update:

```
params[:chordnote] #seems to be nil, so 
params[:chordnote][:note_id] => exception
```

Check the params which are posted to the action. You can see it in your console logs.

Update:

Your link should maybe be something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Remove Note", chord_notes_path(note_id: 1, chord_id: @chord.id), method: :delete, title: "test title", class: "btn btn-large" %>
```

And in your delete action

```
@chord = Chord.find(params[:chord_id])
@note = Note.find(params[:note_id])
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify, but the exception is being found on 2nd line of the destroy controller (@chord = Chord.find(params[:chordnote][:chord_id])), which works fine in the create controller, which is why I'm confused. Is there a way to see the params hash that is passed to the controller when the form is submitted?

Comment: Also, in the form, the delete action is not being called on 'submit', it is a link to the delete action. This could be causing the problem as well.

Comment: please post the console log with the posted data

Comment: I've added to the question above, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: What relationas are between chords and notes?

Comment: It is many-to-many on Chordnote, which has two fields, :chord_id and :note_id.

Comment: Thanks, I think there was a typo in there (chors_path), should that be chord_path? Why not chordnote_path? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. It should be chord_notes_path(...)